# Custom Google Maps Search Box not Localizing returns upon [Enter]

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a basic custom google maps page that is nothing special with the exception of it plotting some locations on the map using inputted addresses within the file.

The issue is regardng the search box.

What happens is that for example when I type "44060", the auto-complete results that appear below the search box are localized to USA (which is great), however if the user presses [Enter], the map does not take them to the first result, or any localized result (it takes them to another far away country).

I know that the SearchBox results are supposed to be:

"Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
            current map's viewport."

However it does not seem to be doing so.

Any help would be apprecaited

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's new to me that the api will do anything on <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, I never realized that until now. But it seems to be very buggy as you said.

You may implement your own handler:

```
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(input,//input-element 
                                           'keydown', 
                                            function (e)
          {
              if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.triggered)
              {
                  google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'keydown',
                  {
                      keyCode: 40
                  })
                  google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'keydown',
                  {
                      keyCode: 13,
                      triggered: true
                  })
              }
          });
```

...it will select the first suggestion from the dropdown when you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Appreciate the answer - apologies if this is a stupid question, how would I implement this solution? what would be the correct syntax for the input-element 'keydown'? When just copy/pasting the code, it says that input is not defined.

Comment: Input is expected to be a HTML-input(the same input you use for the autocomplete/searchbox). I'm not sure how/where you create the searchbox, so i can't tell you exactly how to access it.

Comment: I appreciate your continued help here -

Does this help any?

 ' <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>'

           ' // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
            var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
                document.getElementById('pac-input'));
            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);'